# ARIMA with multiple series

Tags: arima, eviews

i would like to conduct  forecast time series ARIMA model about the disease outbreak on eviews using temp and rainfall as exogenous variable. I am able to forecast all of them alone but not with the impact of temperature and rainfall . can anyone here guide me how to do it on EVIEWS